# Kotlin commonMain with java.io.Serializable

Tags: kotlin, serialization, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlinx.serialization

## Problem

I have a data class in commonMain (called `Person`) that I would like to access from jvmMain as type `java.io.Serializable`.

I have a solution, which is shown below, but I was wondering if this is the best approach. I also found that the library [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization) exists, but I'm not sure if it can be a solution.

## Current code and solution: expected and actual types

This code works fine, although the required DummyInterface may be a bit useless.

```
// CommonMain
expect interface Serializable

data class Person(val name: String) : Serializable
```

```
// jsMain
interface DummyInterface

actual typealias Serializable = DummyInterface
```

```
//jvmMain
actual typealias Serializable = java.io.Serializable

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val p1: java.io.Serializable = Person("abc")
    println(p1)
}
```

## Tried and failed code with kotlinx.serialization

```
// gradle.kotlin.kts

plugins {
    application
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.4.32"
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "1.4.32"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    jvm {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "11"
        }
        withJava()
    }
    js(IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {}
    }

    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0")
            }
        }
        val jvmMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.1.0")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```
// commonMain/kotlin/Person.kt
import kotlinx.serialization.*

@Serializable
data class Person(val name: String)
```

```
// jvmMain/kotlin/main.kt
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Fails with: "Type mismatch: inferred type is Person but Serializable was expected"
    val p1: java.io.Serializable = Person("abc")
    println(p1)
}
```

I know why it fails with a type mismatch, but I would hoping that the kotlinx.serialization plugin would magically add the interface java.io.Serializable to the Person data class.

## Question

1. Is solution with expected and actual types, the best solution for this problem?
2. Would kotlinx.serialization also be able to provide a solution? If so, what code should I alter?

Answer (score 3):

`kotlinx.serialization` wasn't exactly developed as an `java.io.Serializable` abstraction or something. It's a purely kotlin serialization library, for serializing/deserializing `JSON` objects.

Yes, your first approach is a proper solution I'd say.
There is a similar implementation for `Parcelize`, you could check out [moko-parcelize](https://github.com/icerockdev/moko-parcelize/blob/master/parcelize/src/androidMain/kotlin/dev/icerock/moko/parcelize/Parcelize.kt), it's doing the same thing.